# ID and class attributes in HTML5

Tags: html, class

"The id attribute got more classy in HTML5" is written at some pages. If I use class attribute instead of id, does it conform to HTML5? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're talking about [this article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class). Well, nothing has really changed — `class`es and `id`s are used the same way as in HTML4.

Except one thing: The HTML4 spec says the following

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens (“-“),
>   underscores (“_”), colons (“:”), and periods (“.”).

However, in the HTML5 spec, the requirement for `id`s is much less rigid

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element’s home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.

So HTML5 `id`s can accept more characters, which is what [the article you're reffering to](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) is talking about.

Answer (score 5):

The attributes still have two different purposes:

- `class` can contain multiple classes and multiple elements can have the same classes
- `id` contains a single ID and that ID can only be used for **one** element.

The statement you quoted exists because some restrictions on how an ID must look like [have been lifted in HTML5](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) - classes never had those restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `ID` and `class` is that the `ID` has to be unique at one page but the `class` can be used multiply times.

Both is valid HTML 5, you can validate your page here: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has really changed with HTML5 in that respect. IDs are still unique, and classes can be shared across elements. Not sure what the quote was referring to.

Comment: OK I have seen @ThiefMaster's reference. Makes sense, but for all intent and purposes nothing has really changed. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

`class` is for generic purpose and `id` is for unique identification purpose. I mean, id uniquely identifies an element and class specifies a group elements to have the same type of behavior. I hope, it clears the prupose of `class` and `id`.