# jQuery dynamically created checkbox change event

Tags: jquery

I have checkboxes created dynamically on the page after an ajax call.

Using a few posts in here I was able to attach event to the container div of the checkboxes and the event fires now.
HTML

```
<div class="AvailableProducts" id="AvailableProducts">
     <ul><input type="checkbox" id="availableProduct" value="Apple" class="productsSelected"><span>Apple</span> 
     <br><input type="checkbox" id="availableProduct" value="Orange" class="productsSelected"><span>Orange</span> <br>
     </ul>
</div>
```

And I've the event wired up like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AvailableAdvertisers').live('change', 'input:checkbox', function () {
            alert('Fired!');
        });
 });
```

Now I do not know how to get which checkbox was checked.
Thanks.

Edit:
Got it. I can do that with below code

```
$(this + ":checked").val()
$(this + ":checked + span").text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input.productsSelected:checked')
```

Comment: I came across something similar. Thanks. Selecting your answer as yours is the nearest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add  a rel or a value attribute. Then you can use the `.rel()` or `.attr()` method to acquire those attributes in plain text.

for example, if you have a checkbox with `value="chevy"`

```
var checkboxName = $('.mycheckbox').value();
```

is going to give you a variable with the value `"chevy"`

Good Luck 
-Brian

Comment: I want only the boxes that are checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rhJzJ/2/

As an aside you are using the same ID on multiple elements which is wrong.

Comment: Should have mentioned. The thing works in JSFiddle because it's static. On my page those are created dynamically and hence I have to attach event to the container div. Thanks.

Comment: If you read the code in the attached fiddle I've also bound the event using jQuery.on() which in the supplied syntax is the preferred way to attach events for dynamically created elements.

Comment: On the id thing. Why is it wrong? I figured this way I will be able to select a group easily. I know, I can also do that using class, I am just not sure at this point. But would like to know why is it bad to use same Id. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, did not see that. I've voted your answer as helpful. Thanks.

Comment: q:-) -- re the ID issue, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267151/id-and-class-attributes-in-html5