# Why can't I refer to all attributes the same way?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an *input* tag dynamically and it has the following attributes.

```
<input id='beep' id2='boop'></input>
```

While I can refer to the first one by either of the two syntaxes below

```
var tag = document.getElementById("beep");
alert(tag.id);
alert(tag.attributes["id"]);
```

I'm forced to use the latter one when it comes to my custom attribute *id2*. Why?

```
var tag = document.getElementById("beep");
alert(tag.id2); // doesn't work - I get *undefined*
alert(tag.attributes["id2"]);
alert(tag["id2"]); // doesn't work - I get *undefined*
```

Comment: [ID and class attributes in HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267151/id-and-class-attributes-in-html5).

Comment: On a side note, `attributes["foo"]` gives you an attribute node (which happens to show up as a string in the alert). There is `.getAttribute("foo")` to get the string value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing two things here: HTML and DOM. HTML has the concept of tags and attributes, whereas DOM has the concept of nodes and attributes and although they seem to be similar, they are independent technologies (at its core at least).

Only official HTML attributes (and maybe not even all of them) are mapped to DOM attributes when the DOM element is created. The also might get modified in this process. Which attributes are available on DOM nodes is defined in the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html) and [HTML DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html).

Example for the `value` attribute of an `input` element:

> When the `type` attribute of the element has the value `"text"`, `"file"` or `"password"`, this represents the current contents of the corresponding form control, in an interactive user agent. Changing this attribute changes the contents of the form control, but does not change the value of the HTML `value` attribute of the element. When the `type` attribute of the element has the value `"button"`, `"hidden"`, `"submit"`, `"reset"`, `"image"`, `"checkbox"` or `"radio"`, this represents the HTML value attribute of the element. See the value attribute definition in HTML 4.01.

Or the `class` HTML attribute which is `className` in DOM:

> The `class` attribute of the element. This attribute has been renamed due to conflicts with the `"class"` keyword exposed by many languages. See the `class` attribute definition in HTML 4.01.

You can have access to all HTML attributes via [`.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute).

Comment: So, `getAttribute`, rather than `.attribute['id2']`?

Comment: @Andreas: I honestly don't know, I think both are fine. The difference might just be what pimvdb said in his comment.

Answer (score 4):

Only standard attributes have related properties, `id2` is non-standard so it doesn't have an associated property.

Comment: It should also be noted that properties semantically differ from attributes. The OP's code would "work" for e.g. `value`, but you'd obtain different values.

Comment: Oh, I though it was just a syntactic sugar for the other syntax to make it shorter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers do support what your trying to do but I don't know exactly which, for custom attributes use `<input data-id2="boop" />` and access it like this:

```
var tag = document.getElementById("beep");
var id2 = tag.dataset.id2
```

See for [Element Dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset)

Comment: So it's safest to always go `.attributes["nameOfTheAttribute"]`?

Comment: This is interesting, what is the browser support for dataset?